# Native Base Input Component doesn't support React useRef Hook getting "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')

Tags: react-native, native-base

[image]

```
    <Input
    ref={nameRef}
    onSubmitEditing={() => emailRef.current.focus()}
    returnKeyType={"next"}
   />

    <Input
    ref={emailRef}
   />
```

Tried getRef as-well but getting the same error. Works with TextInput component from ReactNative.

Using NativeBase version 3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

For nativeBase's input component you need to use a getRef prop:

```
let inputElement = useRef(null);

 <Input
  getRef={input => {
    inputElement = input;
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Like I said I also tried getRef and it didn't work. It's because ref is coming back as null

Answer (score 0):

Something easy shouldn't be too difficult but when you're using typescript you got no choice.

Nothing in the docs either.

But below is what works for me.

```
const inputRef = useRef<any>()

// input
<Input onSubmitEditing={()=> inputRef.current.focus() />

<Input ref={ref => inputRef.current = ref } />
```

¯_(ツ)_/¯